# Karate UI: How to click a specific checkbox with same class name

Tags: karate

Scenario: A bunch of checkboxes rowed up all the the same class name. Using the 'rightOf' for the checkbox names doesn't work in this specific case.

[image]

The above images shows the div has a id, but it can't be clicked. The clickable part is identified with a shared class name with multiple other similar checkboxes.

Question: How do I click on a third or fourth checkbox sharing the same class name?

Comment: My apologies, done.  Any chance for the assist on the question above? I'll ensure to confirm/vote answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can do a `locateAll()` and *then* navigate:

```
* locateAll('.myclassname')[2].click()
```

For more advanced filtering, read the docs on using a "filter condition" with `locateAll()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#locateall-with-filter

For completeness, if you can get hold of the parent of the bunch: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#tree-walking

```
* parent.children[2].click()
```

Comment: I didn't think about the parent child option.  That may work better than my original approach, however it's not really working for me.  I'll add a screen of the elements I'm trying to navigate to.

Comment: @Puti works for me™, so follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks Peter, I appreciate your time.  I'll try to clean up my original post with more info so other user may gain benefit from this post.

Comment: @Puti if it makes it easier try to find a public web page that replicates your problem and edit your question. all the best