# Any alternative to click on an icon <i> in Karate dynamically apart from friendly locators?

Tags: ui-automation, karate

is there any alternative to click on an ICON  in Karate which is placed rightOf a particular row?
Because I am trying to click one using:

`* rightOf('{}Some Text').find('i').click()`  but failing to do so, whereas the same code with other tagName is working fine like 'span', 'img' etc. I tried using locate() method as well so as to get that icon and click on it. Used near() function But that's not working as well.

Hence, wanted to know how can this be done using some alternative to click on an icon/image according to the dynamic match as per the input given by user.

Comment: sorry, no easy answer sir. also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63894989/143475 - and as alwsys, if something is lacking, you are welcome to contribute code or switch to another framework