# Need to store attribute values of a table for assertion in Karate

Tags: html, ui-automation, karate

I have a case where locator doesn't have a text value but it's attribute named title has a text value that I need to assert. While writing custom locator for it I can only get the text value which is "" and not specific attribute value say title = "#abcdd".

Example:

```
<div class="table-cell" role="cell" table-field= "risk" title="high">high</div>
```

Has `high` as value which I can get

Whereas,

```
<div class="table-cell" role="cell" table-field= "colour" title="#abcdd"></div>
```

Doesn't have any text value but need to get title attribute value `#abcdd` in this case.

Need a generic code to get all such title attribute values present inside this table.
Where are the things going wrong? Any way I can handle this? Or that text value needs to be included in html?

Using karate as Automation test tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an attribute: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#attribute

```
* def temp = attribute('.table-cell', 'title')
```

And if you have an `Element` reference, you can call `.attribute('title')` on it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#chaining

But always keep in mind you can call the DOM JS API on any element, any time. So I leave it as a homework for you to figure out how to get the results of [`Element.attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes), ask a new question with specifically what you tried if needed.

Make sure you read about `locateAll()` with filter, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63894989/143475

And also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66900081/143475

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas, scriptAll() worked fine in that case!