# Javascript functions not working in maven project in eclipse

Tags: javascript, karate

I am using karate framework and I want to use js function in it.
Let me explain in detail

I have a requirement where in I need to fetch the id value which is dynamic inside an iframe. So I want to use `getElementByTagName('iframe')` function but it is not working. It says ReferenceError: "document" is not defined'

Can someone let me know what all libraries or plugins or dependencies should be added to make this work?

`* def elementId =
"""
 function()
    {
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var id = list[i].id;
        if (id && id.search(/flex-microform-/) != -1) {
            return(id);
        }
    }
    return(null);
}
"""
 * def temp = call elementId
    * print temp`

Comment: also read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66718464/143475

Comment: Can you please let me know how i can do it using karate itself.. maybe using scriptAll()?

Comment: you need to read the docs. everything is explained there. and to be clear - NO extra JS libraries are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library

```
<script src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Where should i be adding this library?

Comment: just add it at the Start of your code