# Karate UI : find an element by dynamic attribute

Tags: karate

I have this element

```
<select id="26" class="case-field" componentid="48" selected="" name="TestDropDown2356" placeholder="TestDropDown2356"><option value="">Select</option><option value="a">a</option><option value="b">b</option><option value="c">c</option></select>
```

And I want to locate it by name attribute, but the name is a variable with a randomn number generator.
So far It worked with script like this :

```
* def firstOption = script("//select[@name='TestDropDown']","_.textContent")
```

But like this does not work.

```
 * def filedName = "TestDropDown " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1
 * def firstOption = script("//select[@name='"+ filedName + "']","_.textContent")
```

How sholud i manage this ?

Comment: try approaches like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66900081/143475