KarateUI - Finding all the web elements using LocateAll and navigating through Loop
I've been having trouble around traversing through labels/text and storing and iterating.
So the scenario is we are using Karate for UI and API in our project , I have 4 checkboxes on a web page in line and each of them have text attached to it like country names China India Americas UKI. And underlying application is designed in AngularJS
Now I want to find the common locator and traverse through each one of the locator and store the label names and then verify with the expected values.
This is my POM.xml we are using.
<!-- Karate core -->

    com.intuit.karate
    karate-core
    1.2.0
    test


<!-- Karate JUnit 4 support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Optionally include karate-apache for API testing support -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

This is the statement which gives me all 4 countries name:

def checkboxes   =  locateAll('//rca-checkbox/label/span[1]')

The whole script is below:
I have tried all possible combinations checked google/youtube but it didn't work.
Scenario: Verify that the labels of the checkboxes match expected values
* def checkboxes = locateAll('//rca-checkbox/label/span[1]')
* def labels = []
# Loop through each checkbox and collect the text
* karate.forEach(checkboxes, function(checkbox) {
    * def label = checkbox.text()
    * karate.appendTo(labels, label.trim())
})

* def expectedLabels = ['APAC', 'Americas', 'Central', 'DE/EMEA', 'UKI']
* match labels == expectedLabels`

`
Can you please help me with the above issue, how can i test simple scenario using Karate UI.
And also the dependencies are correct or we should change something there as well?
Since we are using both Karate version 0.9.6 and 1.2.0.  can this potentially lead to conflicts or unexpected behavior due to version discrepancies.?

every app is different and will have different UI challenges due to JS, it doesn't matter if it is angular, react etc. there is no way for anyone to answer this without access to the actual HTML. please refer to other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66900081/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/76698661/143475
