# No locator found by Karate framework

Tags: user-interface, testing, xpath, ui-automation, karate

Could you please help me?
I have a button which I need to click on. Checking it in the console, the XPath of this button returns 2 elements and I need to click on the 2nd one. So, at least these 2 locators are returning correctly my button:
("//a[@href='/organization/createorganization']")[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqouo.png)]
("//*[text()='mybuttonText']")[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqouo.png)]

[image]

I´m trying to create an automated test using Karate.

- def temp = locateAll("/a[@href='/organization/createorganization']")
- match karate.sizeOf(temp) == 2
- temp[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqouo.png)].click()

My problem is that the size of temp is always 0.That means it doesn't find the locator?! Why wouldn´t find the locator? I tried also to introduce a delay, sleep time, the result is always the same. I can see visually when running the test that it doesn't click on the button. I´ve tried with both XPaths that I mentioned above and other XPaths that I could have come up with, but I get always the same - 0.
[image]

Please, do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your locator is wrong. There's no way to tell from the limited amount of info in your question.

But try this:

```
* def temp = locateAll("//a[@href='/organization/createorganization']")
```

Or use other options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63894989/143475

If all else fails, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I realized I missed one "/" when posting the message , even I used the correct locator in my test. Either way, I tried again with the locator you mentioned and it seems that `locateAll()` is not working for me. I made a quick check using `locateAll()` for another test scenario and I get the same result - locator is not found. Aparently, I can´t find any locator using `locateAll()`. But it works just fine using `click()` on the locator. For now, I solved the problem using `click("//a[@href='/organization/createorganization']")`.